# Cracking the coding Interview: Unique Character (Working of if block)

Tags: java

I want to understand the working of if block from the below code. For example: if my string is rock, then the ASCII would be `char_set[r] = 114` 
    `char_set[o] = 111`,`char_set[c] = 99`,`char_set[k] = 107`. So for the first time when `char_set[r] = 114` will come to if block then what is going to be checked? Since `char_set` is boolean type so it could be either true or false but according to my understanding initially `char_set[r] = 114` is not set to either true or false. So how can we check if it is either true or false inside the if block. I have looked at the previous related questions but my question was different and couldn't find anything. This question is taken from the book Cracking the coding interview.

```
public boolean isuniqueChars2(String str) {

       if (str.length() > 128) 
        return false;

    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) {
            return false;
      }
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How can `char_set[r] = 114` when `char_set` is a `boolean[]`?

Comment: In Java, you are not using ASCII. `charAt` can return 0 to 65535, which is a [Unicode/UTF-16 code unit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode).Please take some time later to understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are initialized with default values upon creation. Default value for `boolean` type is `false`.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: @Jashaszun, I assume that it answers it, I understood `char_set[r] = 114` notation as `char_set[r] "is the same as" char_set[114]`, and concluded that the author does not know about default value for array items.

Comment: But the default value for `boolean`s is `false`, which is intended for this sample of code. Whether or not the asker understands this is irrelevant, since there's no problem with this.

Comment: @Jashaszun, "So for the first time when char_set[r] = 114 will come to if block then **what is going to be checked**?", do you still think that the problem is not in understanding the default value?

Comment: I believe that the misunderstanding is in the usage of characters for indexing into the boolean array, not in the default value of booleans.

Answer (score 0):

What `char_set` does is for every ASCII value, it stores a `boolean` value for whether you've seen that character before or not.

So essentially, it is saying this (in somewhat pseudocode):

```
for (every character in the string) {
    int val = str.charAt(i); //get the current character;
    if (char_set[val]) // if (we've seen the current character already)
        return false; // not made of unique characters
    char_set[val] = true; //store that we've seen the current character;
}
return true; // we got through all the characters, so it must now be unique.
```

What is really happening is that if your input string is `rock`, then `char_set['r']` is `true`, and so is `char_set['o']`, `char_set['c']`, and `char_set['k']`.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `char_set` are `boolean`s.  They are all initialized to the default value for that type (`false`), when you create the array.  The values of some of those elements may be tested in

```
        if (char_set[val]) //...
```

(yielding one of the two possible values of type `boolean`, whichever was most recently set) and may be set to `true` in

```
        char_set[val] = true;
```

in each case, `val` is the *index* of the element involved, not the value to set or read.

Note, however, that this code has at least two significant problems:

1. `String.charAt()` returns values of type `char`, whose numeric range goes up to `65535`.  Therefore, the code presented can easily generate an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
2. `String`s are indexed starting from `0`, so the first character in the string is not included in the analysis.  In a general sense, this could be intentional, but in an "analyze this code" sense it is important to recognize.